# Undefined array variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have an undefined javascript error in my code. I can't find what causes the problem.
I load CSV file with ajax and parse by lines and columns separated by tabs.
Everything is fine but I got only one undefined variable.

What am I missing? please advise me.

my data file looks like below:

```
Thành phố Hà Nội    01  Quận Ba Đình    001 Phường Phúc Xá  00001   Phường
Thành phố Hà Nội    01  Quận Ba Đình    001 Phường Trúc Bạch    00004   Phường
Thành phố Hà Nội    01  Quận Ba Đình    001 Phường Vĩnh Phúc    00006   Phường
```

and my javascript code below:

```
   $(function() {
    var fileName = "data.txt";

    $.ajax({
        url: fileName,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            //console.log(lines);

            $('h1').text(lines.length + ' lines');

            //var cols = [];
            var cols = new Array();
            var col_name = new Array();
            //var col_name = [];



            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

                var cells = lines[i].split('\t');

                for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {

                    cells[j] = $.trim(cells[j]);

                    if(j == 0) col_name[j] = 'state';
                    if(j == 1) col_name[j] = 'code1';
                    if(j == 2) col_name[j] = 'province';
                    if(j == 3) col_name[j] = 'code2';
                    if(j == 4) col_name[j] = 'area';
                    if(j == 5) col_name[j] = 'code3';
                    if(j == 6) col_name[j] = 'street';

                    cols[i] += col_name[j] + '=\'' + cells[j] + '\', ';   

                }

                cols[i] = cols[i].replace(/\,+$/, '');
                cols[i] = cols[i].slice(0, -2);


                str = "INSERT INTO table SET " + cols[i] + ";";
                $('ul').append('<li>' + str + '</li>');

            }

        }
    });

});
```

The result of my code is below:

```
INSERT INTO table SET **undefined**state='Thành phố Hà Nội', code1='01', province='Quận Ba Đình', code2='001', area='Phường Phúc Xá', code3='00001', street='Phường';
INSERT INTO table SET **undefined**state='Thành phố Hà Nội', code1='01', province='Quận Ba Đình', code2='001', area='Phường Trúc Bạch', code3='00004', street='Phường';
INSERT INTO table SET **undefined**state='Thành phố Hà Nội', code1='01', province='Quận Ba Đình', code2='001', area='Phường Vĩnh Phúc', code3='00006', street='Phường';
```

As you see the result, there's undefined on every line.

Comment: 15 lines
INSERT INTO table SET undefinedstate='Thành phố Hà Nội', code1='01', province='Quận Ba Đình', code2='001', area='Phường Phúc Xá', code3='00001', street='Phường';
INSERT INTO table SET undefinedstate='Thành phố Hà Nội', code1='01', province='Quận Ba Đình', code2='001', area='Phường Trúc Bạch', code3='00004', street='Phường';
INSERT INTO table SET undefinedstate='Thành phố Hà Nội', code1='01', province='Quận Ba Đình', code2='001', area='Phường Vĩnh Phúc', code3='00006', street='Phường';

Comment: include the error you are getting in console, that would help a lot

Comment: Whats the variable your getting an undefined for and is it the last time that variable is iterated like cells[6] is undefined as if its an EOT when your expecting to parse a variable before the EOT?

Comment: cols[i]   - it's the variable I am getting undefined. but I have already defined on the upper lines. I got an undefined on only col[0] .. other col[i]s are fine.

Comment: My first comment is the result of my code. As you see, there's undefined on every line.

Comment: can you provide original data.text file? tried read in local but not success

Comment: My original data.file is on my question. 
Each column is seperated by tab (\t).

Thành phố Hà Nội 01 Quận Ba Đình 001 Phường Phúc Xá 00001 Phường
Thành phố Hà Nội 01 Quận Ba Đình 001 Phường Trúc Bạch 00004 Phường
Thành phố Hà Nội 01 Quận Ba Đình 001 Phường Vĩnh Phúc 00006 Phường

Comment: The cols array items are initially undefined, so you're adding a string to undefined.  If you were going to go with this approach you'd need to ensure an empty string is present before `cols[i] += ...`, or something similar.

Comment: thanks.. I didn't initialize the cols[i] ..  I thought a statement "var cols = []"  is the initialization of variables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cols[i] += col_name[j] 
//      ^ The undefined comes from the +=
//        cols[i] is undefined here, so 
//        you're adding a string to that
```

You're mixing `update` with `insert` in the sql statement? Or is this not sql?

Here's a snippet that simplifies your function for handling the data. It creates valid sql insert statements. Maybe it's of use.

```js
const txt = `Thành phố Hà Nội    01  Quận Ba Đình    001 Phường Phúc Xá  00001   Phường
Thành phố Hà Nội    01  Quận Ba Đình    001 Phường Trúc Bạch    00004   Phường
Thành phố Hà Nội    01  Quận Ba Đình    001 Phường Vĩnh Phúc    00006   Phường`;

console.log(processTxt(txt));

function processTxt(data) {
  const lines = data.split(/\n/);
  const col_names = ['state', 'code1', 'province', 'code2', 'area', 'code3', 'street'];
  let tableInsertLines = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const cells = lines[i].split(/\s+|\t/).slice(0, col_names.length);
    tableInsertLines.push(`INSERT INTO some_table (${col_names}) values('${
      cells.join("','")}');`);
  }
  return tableInsertLines;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```